# Comparing Models based on two different sample sets of a single data set

Tags: model-evaluations, sampling

I want to compare the performance of two different ML models like M1 and M2. I have a very huge data set and having two different downsampling of this data set, call them S1 and S2. Can I compare the performance of M1 on S1 and M2 on S2? (Suppose that M1 and M2 are large enough)